# Using fdsymbol and fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fdsymbol

I'd like to use the `fdsymbol` package together with the `fedra serif b` Opentype font. I'm having some problems with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{fedraserifpro-b-book.otf}[
%BoldFont = fedraserifpro-b-medium.otf, 
%ItalicFont = fedraserifpro-b-bookitalic.otf,
%BoldItalicFont = fedraserifpro-b-mediumita.otf]

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sigma(w | xv)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `XeLaTeX`, I get the following error

```
LaTeX error: Command '\mathdollar' already defined.
```

I'm not sure wether the problem is machine-specific or not. Any ideas?

EDIT: After using `\let\mathdollar\undefined` the code compiles, but the result is

[image]

Instead of

[image]

Comment: give the command `\let\mathdollar\undefined` just before `\begin{document}`... Possibly `fdsymbol` package is trying to define it at the beginning of the document... but finds it already defined... Un-define it just before get there and let it redefine it then... But I am not sure if you should use this package with `XeLaTeX`...

Comment: With `\let\mathdollar\undefined` the code compiles, but I'm still not getting the right font. I've updated the post to show what I mean

Comment: Have you tried this way (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96028/120578)?

Comment: I saw that post but I can't put `fdsymbol` inside of `\setmathfont`.

Comment: Usually font packages are supposed to be used with `LaTeX` and `pdfLaTeX`... Not with `XeLaTeX` that is created to use system fonts... I suppose that the error means that the creator of the package has not created it to be compatible with `XeLaTeX`... Try to use `Fedora`  font family that is the equivalent real font to this package's font

Comment: Could you post some code showing how to use `Fedora` as the main math font in `XeLaTeX`?

Comment: fdsymbol doesn't redefine letters, it only defines lots of symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download some Fedora Fonts (I don't really know where you could find it, but it should be compatible with math)

Then:

after adding the font on your system, you could run the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
Test
\begin{equation}
\boldmath{\sigma(w | xv)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

That would give:

[image]

PS: I don't know where the original font should be fount and just add code that could use different main font and different font for math with some fonts available on Linux systems and on Overleaf (so that you can test the code).

Comment: Using `mathspec`, I simply added `\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{fedraserifpro-b-bookitalic.otf}` and it seems to work fine. Two final questions: 1) what is the use of the `(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]` options? 2) I'm trying to get bold fonts in math environemnts using the `\boldsymbol` command, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Check this answer of @egreg for bold math using `mathspec`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198138/120578 (I just copyed from the link I provided and you possibly not need all the options... Someone of us should read `mathspec`s documentation, but I don't need it right now :P )... [Just making fun with my non-knowledge on it]

Comment: aha ok got it :)